# Setting Security permissions on Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ)

Tags: security, permissions, msmq, user-permissions, windows-security

I am trying to add permissions to a group for Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ). On Windows Server in the Server Manager under Features I right-click directly on MessageQueuing which is the top level > Properties > Security. I want to make sure my Windows Service or Web Application will have permission to Create a new queue if necessary.

When clicking apply I get the following message:

```
The security descriptor cannot be set.
Error: Access is denied.
```

Then followed by another message:

```
Unable to save permission changes on .
(null)
```

I already tried going to Security > Advanced > Owner and change the owner to me, but I get the same messages when I do this.

I am logged in as an Administrator on the server.

Comment: A bit of a hack - http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2012/03/msmqsecurity-descriptor-cannot-be-set.html